# How is a Rydberg Blockade Radius defined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, atomic-physics

Rydberg blockade is a phenomena in 3 or more level systems of Rydberg dressed atoms.

Comment: The wikipedia artilce on [Rydberg atoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_atom) cites several papers from [2007](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0701120) and [2008](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2960) that [have](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.0758) "Rydberg blockage" in their titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In zero electric field, the interactions energy between two Rydberg atoms is $U=C_6 r^{-6}$. If the Rydberg transition is driven with an (effective) Rabi frequency $\Omega$, then the blockade radius is $$R_b = \left( \frac{\hbar\Omega}{C_6} \right)^{-1/6}$$ If one atom is excited to the Rydberg state, a second atom will be detuned by just enough to prevent a complete transition.